# Exchange Calendar in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, exchange

My client have their corporate calendar as an exchange calendar.  How can I setup my SharePoint to view the exchange calendar entries in the SharePoint calendar.  Currently if you connect to exchange it only shows on SharePoint the logged in users' exchange calendar.  I want all the users to see only this one calendar.  How do I set that up?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to import your exchange calendar to sharepoint, but you are able to create a new calendar in SharePoint and open it in Outlook by clicking on "calendar" in the ribbon bar of SharePoint (if you are in a SharePoint calendar). Then the SharePoint calendar will open as normal calendar in your Outlook client and you are able to copy your events from your exchange calendar to the SharePoint calendar. Then you will see them in the sharepoint calendar and also users are able to sync it to outlook, if they don't want to open SharePoint.

Comment: So there is no way that you can setup the calendar to invite users from that exchange calendar - the Corporate Calendar. (In other words, that the invite shows that it comes from the 'Corporate Calendar' and responses is shown in the corporate calendar)  Is the only method that you schedule a meeting, you have to do it form your own outlook account, invite attendees and the invite will come from your outlook account and responses will go to your outlook account - one can only copy the event to the exchange (Corporate Calendar)?